# Is there a way to export a sql server database from a windows form app to a web app in visual studio?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

i'm working on a vb application that uses a sql server database in a desktop module(windows form) which is supposed to export this database to a web application(in vb.net).
so my question is : is there a way i can export this database from my desktop app to the web app and vice versa(from the web abck to the desktop app)
thnx in advance

Comment: Why would you need to "export" your database? Just access it from either application.

Comment: What does "export" even mean in this context?

Comment: * i need to export the  database inorder to save the users data (a user can only access to the web app) then import it to the desktop application where an administator(cant access to the web app) could save it  in his computer

Comment: *export means sending the database from the desktop application to the web application

Comment: Well, you likely can export the sql mdf file right up to the server (ftp), but it will over write any  changes made by anyone else running that local copy of SQL server. So just a export of the data not really the question unless this is a done time upload. If you need something with mutli-user, then you have to use say .net sync framework. The database on the web server is NOT exposed with ease since if it was, then everyone on the internet would be able to grab or upload and overwrite that data. If it just new records, then you could send up a csv file and process it local on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Database servers have the possibility to Replicate their Database even over the Internet. That would be the simplest solution and you can find some very good articles. If you have differnet Databases types, this can be tricky or even impossible.

Second possibility: make a database dump, ftp the dump to your server, and the a program imports that dump. You must read if the "Web database" cann import that dump

Otherwise you have to have a server component that can Receive Data from your windos app and save that in the "Web Database".
Your windws Program is the client who opens a connection to the web app, opens the dDatabse and sends the database, for example as sql statement text to the wep app.
The cpnnection should be encrypted, and your wep app as server also shold include a login procedure, with very good passwort. You know that every Ip gets scanned permanently.
for such client server combination, you will find also lots of examples.
Good luck